# C# componente de fluxograma/organograma

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Estou fazendo uma aplicação desktop para configuração de produto, tendo como campos de seleção várias opções relacionadas aos mesmos, ex: modelo, tensão, aplicação...
onde ao selecionar cada uma, as demais abaixo são filtradas de acordo com o que existe cadastrado no banco de dados, ex: ao selecionar modelo x, em um combobox de tensão será filtrado as opções para este modelo.

Até aí tudo bem, é bem simples, o problema é que a necessidade do cliente é ter a funcionalidade citada acima e também uma representação dos "caminhos" possíveis por meio de uma espécie de fluxograma ou organograma, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima a representação se inicia por exemplo com os 2 modelos possíveis, em seguida as possibilidades de configuração para cada um.

Pesquisei muito sobre componentes para fazer esse tipo de representação, já tendo os dados cadastrados e relacionados no bando, porém não tive sucesso.

Comment: Isso é possível de fazer com um `UserControl` onde fica agregada a informação de cada nodo e depois utiliza-se linhas para as ligações, mas não é muito simples de se implementar. Os nodos são todos iguais?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar TreeView? A representação ficaria um pouco diferente mas o resultado seria o mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe a necessidade explícita de esse fluxograma ser gerado automaticamente? Imaginei aqui que esse tipo de fluxograma pode ter varias particularidades, já que se trata de configuração de produto, podendo tornar inviável, dependendo da sua necessidade.

Em caso de não ser explícita essa necessidade, recomendo possibilitar um usuario chave para fazer a construção desse fluxograma manualmente, por meio de uma tela que possibilite isso. Utilizando somente Canvas, Rectangle, Path e Grid é possível fazer isso sem problemas. O produto final ficaria parecido com uma espécie de Paint.

Comment: Justamente isso que comecei fazer, e está atendendo muito bem. Mesmo assim , obrigado